# Can't import modules that are there

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

From command line I can't import appengine, this might be something with my python path:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from google.appengine.ext import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import datastore
  File "google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 62, in <module>
    from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_query
  File "google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 64, in <module>
    from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_index
  File "google/appengine/datastore/datastore_index.py", line 60, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import validation
  File "google/appengine/api/validation.py", line 51, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
>>>
```

I don't want duplicate installations, I want to point the Python interpretor to where the missing module is. How do I make the interpretor find the app engine modules from the command prompt? In the application these imports are working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

appending:

```
/usr/local/google_appengine/:/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/:/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/
```

to your PYTHONPATH environment variable should do the trick (your SDK location may vary).

Comment: Sometimes the order you add to your pythonpath may make a difference as some libraries can conflict in the wrong order. Also check that your modules are installed for the same version of Python. You might have installed them for Python 2.6 and note have them in Python 2.7.

Comment: I had to change yaml to yaml-3.10 as @Clyde's answer mentioned

Answer (score 8):

For appengine 1.9.6 google has created a new directory "yaml-3.10" that contains the yaml module. I added "[appengine install directory]/google_appengine/lib/yaml-3.10" to PYTHONPATH in my .bashrc file and that solved this problem. BTW: I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 6):

yaml is not installed in your current setup. yaml package is included with google_appengine in the lib folder. the setup.py script in the folder will add the yaml package to your current python

```
cd google_appengine/lib/yaml
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with some explanation of why the asker is having the problem and how running these commands will fix their problem.